# Change code source location programmatically when invoking a method

Tags: java, class, invoke

I have the following problem:
I want to invoke a class from an external jar, which uses

```
TheClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

to get the current running jar File.
When I invoke this method, it throws an exception, because getCodeSource() now return the path of the jar files which invokes it.
I cannot change the code from the other jar file. Is there any way to change the returned location of getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() programmatically from the class which invokes this method? 
I use this code to invoke the method:

```
        Class<?> c = this.loadClass(NameOfTheClass);
        Method m = c.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[]{ args });
```

Comment: ClassLoaders are a crucial part of Java’s security model, so it’s unlikely they can be spoofed.  I would avoid a library with such broken code, if that’s an option.  That getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() line of code is broken in at least two other ways.

Comment: @VGR I have to use this library /: There is sadly no way around.